# MongoDB, how to use $geoNear on a field resolved by $lookup

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

**CONTEXT**

My project looks like a simple social network. In my database, I have a collection of "news feed items", each of these has the ID of the post to which they refer, and the recipient (owner) of the feed.
This is my schema created with the nodejs driver Mongoose (But I think that the question can be indirect to all those who know MongoDB regardless of the drivers):

```
export const NewsFeedSchema = new Schema({
  ownerId: { type: Types.ObjectId, required: true },
  post: { type: Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Post' },
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  isSeen: { type: Boolean, default: false },
});
```

Instead, this is the posts schema (the significant part is the "location" field):

```
export const PostSchema= new Schema({
  authorId: {
    type: Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  body: {
    type: String,
  },
  media: {
    type: String,
  },
  location: {   // <--------
    type: PointSchema,
    required: true,
  },
  created_at: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

PostSchema.index({ authorId: 1 });
PostSchema.index({ location: '2dsphere' });
```

**THE QUESTION**

My question at this point is: how do I request all the feeds of a certain user (ownerId) and which are at a certain distance from a past point?

**WHAT HAVE I TRIED**

I am not an expert on Mongodb, and as soon as the problem was presented to me I immediately thought that the aggregations could be for me. I therefore immediately went to study them.

I managed (after a lot of effort) to formulate an aggregation that first populated the "post" field and then performed the Geospatial Query.
However from what I later discovered on the net, and from the error message I received from Mongodb, that it should not be possible to do this (at least with my approach).

This is my code:

```
items = await this.myModel.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'posts',
      localField: 'post',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'post',
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: '$post',
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      ownerId: Types.ObjectId(ownerId),
    },
  },
  {
    $geoNear: {
      near: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [-73.99279, 40.719296] },
      distanceField: 'dist.calculated',
      maxDistance: 2,
      includeLocs: 'dist.location',
      spherical: true,
    },
  },
]);
```

This is the error message (fairly self-explanatory):
$geoNear is only valid as the first stage in a pipeline.

What I ask is not to make a miracle but, first of all, if something has changed over time with the versions of MongoDB, and, if my approach is not really possible, to give me a tip on another working approach (maybe without exaggeratedly terrible performances if I don't ask too much).
Thanks a lot in advance to everyone.

Comment: You need to start with the geo query and then join the other data.

Comment: Thank you so much for your support. This was the conclusion I had come to by reading other similar problems. My problem is that I have to run the query on the fields of the document that must be "joined". So I guess if I moved the geo query to the beginning it wouldn't work the same